# Calculate time passed with various hours depending on the day?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to calculate how many "periods of hours" have passed since X date until today's date.  This would be simple, given there are 24 hours in a day, however I need to calculate this with varying amounts of hours per weekday.

I only need to count the hours between 0600 to 2000 Monday to Friday, 0600 to 1800 Saturdays and 0900 to 1700 Sundays.
Also Bank Holidays 0900 to 1730 excluding Christmas Day and Boxing Day.

For example, if a date was 27/02/2013  12:00:00, then there have been roughly 9 weekdays and 2 Saturdays and 2 Sundays.  This would therefore bring the total to (assuming the date is 12/03/2013 12:00): 166 hours (126 + 24 + 16) which equates to 3.9 "periods"

Does this make sense?

EDIT: I could actually simply this by taking said date, figuring out how many Weekdays, Saturdays, Sundays and Bank Holidays there have been since said date, and then minus the hours multipled by the number of days just mentioned?

Comment: Do you care about the start time (of day) or are you simply considering whole days? Do you want to do this with formulas or VBA? Which version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by period, but if you want the hours, something like this should do:

```
//NOTE: Adjust the order to match the rules priorities
float hoursOfDay(Date d) {
    if (isHoliday(d))
        return 8.5;
    elsif (isRegular(d))
        return 14;
    elsif (isSaturday(d))
        return ;
    elsif (isSunday(d))
    ...         
}
```

The functions are just checking on the day type (according to the language, these functions should already be there)
    isSaturday(d) = d.dayOftheWeek == DayOfTheWeek.SUNDAY

Then, you would just need to iterate over them:

```
DateTime d1;
DateTime d2;
//NOTE: according to language, d2-d1 is a timespan object
float hours = 0;
for (Date d: d2-d1)
    hours+=hoursOfDay(d);

convertHoursToPeriods(hours);
```

Comment: If these mapping dayType -> hours might change, it would be better to put them in a map object or in an enum with custom values or similar...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using a different method.  Counted the number of days between the dates and multiplied it by the difference in hours

B2 being todays date and C8 being the start date.

**Weekdays**

> =SUM(INT((WEEKDAY(C8-{2,3,4,5,6})+$B$2-C8)/7))

**Saturdays**

> =SUM(INT((WEEKDAY(C8-7)+$B$2-C8)/7))

**Sundays**

> =SUM(INT((WEEKDAY(C8-1)+$B$2-C8)/7))

I could then calculate that on a weekday, there are 14 hours I want to count. So Weekday number multiplied by 14 gives me the number i want.  Repeat for other days :)

Comment: You could do that all in one formula for all days like this: `=SUMPRODUCT(INT((WEEKDAY(C8-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})+$B$2-C8)/7),{8,14,14,14,14,14,12})`.....doesn't take account of holidays, though......